# how to make load codeigniter database library inside a non codeigniter folder / file?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

i have a folder named `superfunctions`

[image]

that folder is in same level with the controller, model and views folder

is it possible to call the the database library inside the php files of that said folder.

I want to use `this->db->query("")` etc...

on or inside

`application/superfunctions/function1.php`

`function1.php` is just pure function / not a class

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to achieve your goal is to make it a helper file.

> /application/helpers/function1.php

**function1.php**

```
<?php
if(!function_exists('function1'))
{
    function function1()
    {
        // Get the CodeIgniter instance by reference
        // Basically, $this from the controller is now $CI within this function
        $CI = &get_instance();

        $CI->db->query("");
        // do whatever

        return 'hi';
    }
}
```

So whenever you need it in your controller then just do:

```
class Welcome extends CI_controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->helper('function1');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo function1();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not create a library with those functions, and autoload that library
On the other hand, you can create a class in you sub folder like

```
<?php
class My_super_class{

    protected $CI;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function do_somthing( $param1 = NULL ){
        //param1 as array
        $this->CI->db->insert('table', $param1);
    }

    public function check_login(){
        $this->CI->load->library('session');

        return ( ! empty($this->CI->session->userdata('id'))) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: hi i know how to create library, it is also what im considering.. but i think i can use the db class directly without calling CI instance.. im currently reading now the DB class and how to instantiate it manually..  the reason i need it to be called manually from separate file is that.. the files inside that folder will be big.. i will mainly just focus on database operations..